# Why hidden input causes ClassCastException

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3, classcastexception

Consider this example.

**Web page**:

```
<h:form>
  <h:outputLabel value="Enter some text:"/>
  <h:inputText value="#{testController.vo.testString}" />
  <h:inputHidden id="test" value="#{testController.vo.id}" />
  <h:commandButton value="Click me" action="#{testController.submitForm}"/>
</h:form>
```

**Controller**:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ValueObject vo = new ValueObject();

    public String submitForm() {
        return null;
    }

    public ValueObject getVo() {
            return vo;
    }

    public void setVo(ValueObject vo) {
        this.vo = vo;
    }

}
```

**ValueObject**:

```
public class ValueObject {

    private Long id;

    private String testString;

    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

As you see, `ValueObject` class has `setId`/`getId` methods. So far, everything is fine.

Now, I want to introduce an interface:

```
public interface Identifiable<T> {
    T getId();
    void setId(T id);
}
```

and have my `ValueObject` implement it:

```
public class ValueObject implements Identifiable<Long> { // remainder omitted }
```

Nothing changed in the `ValueObject` class, rather than now it implements `Identifiable`. But when I try to submit the form again, I get the following stack-trace:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @16,61 value="#{testController.vo.id}": java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:139)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:818)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.test.vo.ValueObject.setId(ValueObject.java:1)
```

As you see, during the *Update Model Values* phase the `ClassCastException` thrown when trying to call `setId` method. This happens only for hidden inputs. If I try to modify my **xhtml** by adding the *converter*, everything works fine:

```
<h:inputHidden id="test" value="#{testController.vo.id}" converter="javax.faces.Long"/>
```

So, why does input behavior change when I just make my `ValueObject` implement an interface with a generic parameter? Is this a Glassfish bug?

**Edit:**
It turned out, that it doesn't depend on whether the input is *hidden* or not. The Glassfish version on which this issue is reproducible is **3.1-b43**.

Comment: I took the time to setup a test project, but I couldn't reproduce it on Tomcat 7.0.23 nor Glassfish 3.1.1 with their default EL impl untouched. What GF version are you using? It might as well be an EL implementation issue. You were right that it should not occur as you redefinied the type in the model object (hence I deleted the wrong answer).

Comment: Thanks for your time, @BalusC! I really appreciate it. I could reproduce this on `Glassfish v 3.1 b43`. Do you think that `GF 3.1.1.` could have changed the `EL` version? If you won't be able to reproduce it on 3.1 either, I'll package a test application later today. Also, are you aware, where can I get the implementation source code for `javax.el` used in Glassfish? I spent almost 2 hours searching with no luck :( Obviously the official page is [here](http://uel.java.net/) but there is no source code.

Comment: I can now confirm, that the issue persists on `Glassfish 3.1.1 (build 12)`. I uploaded my test WAR, so you can check [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?oy7rq47d28btsbt) out. I use **CDI**, so CDI-capable container is required (just warning in case you might be tempted to deploy it on `Tomcat`).

Comment: I've also tested this on `Tomcat 7.0.25`, with `JSF Mojarra 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT` replacing CDI beans with `JSF managed beans`. The issue is reproducible.